# hibernation in a cave or hibernation from a cave?

Tags: idiomatic-language

> The hibernating bears were driven out of their hibernation in a cave
> by the construction workers.
>
> The hibernating bears were driven out of their hibernation from a cave
> by the construction workers.

I honestly think both don't make sense, but how do you say out of their hibernation while still mentioning they were hibernating in a cave? Can you try to say it without making too many changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real need to repeat "hibernation". And "driven out" goes with "cave" not "hibernation"

> The hibernating bears were driven out of their cave by the construction workers.

You could use "disturbed from hibernation" if you do need to repeat the word